# Cucumber CLI Main skipping the feature files

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

I want to execute cucumber tests from cucumber CLI instead of Maven.

I have below code in my Runner class:

```
import io.cucumber.core.cli.Main;

public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main.main(new String[]{"-g", "src/test/java/com/company/project/stepdefinitions", "-t", "Regression", "src/test/resources/features"});
    }
}
```

When I execute it, it doesn't run any tests -

```
0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.163s
```

Any Idea what am I missing ? If I remove the tag then it detects the feature file but says corresponding stepdefinition is missing.

**Main.main(new String[]{"-g", "src/test/java/com/company/project/stepdefinitions/module1/Stepmodule1","src/test/resources/features/module1/ValidateModule1.feature"});**

```
Undefined scenarios:
file:///C:/Users/.../src/test/resources/features/module1/ValidateModule1.feature:5 # To Test Module1

1 Scenarios (1 undefined)
1 Steps (1 undefined)
0m0.228s
```

Am I calling main function in CLI with wrong parameters?

Kind Regards,

Abhi

Comment: The tag in your feature file looks different from the tag on the commandline.

Comment: Your glue path is wrong too. That should be a package name. Like `com.compangy.project`.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje : Thanks, Yes indeed I gave the glue in wrong format.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions.

The below syntax worked for me for giving glue and feature files in a standalone Java class.

```
import io.cucumber.core.cli.Main;

public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main.main(new String[]{"-g", "com.company.project.stepdefinitions","-t", "@Regression","-p", "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:", "src/main/resources/features/"});
    }
}
```